# How to speed up pixel scanning a numpy array

Tags: numpy, webcam, lidar

I have made a distance detector using a webcam and laser to estimate the distance of the laser dot. My plan is to make a cheap 2d ldar system using the raspberry pi.

At first I did pixel scanning using nested python loops, this was way too slow with a scan taking around 2 minutes. Then i tried to speed up the scanning process using numpy arrays. This has brought the time down to 600 milliseconds. However this still is not fast enough. 10 ms would be a more suitable time frame, if i could get it lower than that it would be a bonus. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get a faster scan time?

I am setting a threshold with the numpy arrays , just looking for the reddest pixels using xy_vals = [img_array_rgb] > 236. this gives me an array of true elements where the red dot is. I then find the x,y coordinates of the true elements using nonzero().

Comment: What size is your image? How long does the thresholding take? On my PC, with a 640x480x3 image, the thresholding is about 9% of the total time, and I don't think it is reasonable to expect less than that, i.e. it seems unlikely you will be able to go under 50ms, unless someone comes up with some algorithmic magic. I don't think there is any easy way in numpy to not have to scan the array twice, although that would be easy in Cython or C. What do you do with the indices of the red dot after finding them?

Comment: https://pytech-solution.blogspot.com/2018/02/fast-pixel-processing-with-opencv-and.html You can speed up to 1000x, Go to this link